# breadcrumbs how to get information about route having only its url

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, angular7, breadcrumbs

I am having trouble implementing breadcrumbs

My routes are like:

(I cannot change its design so that detail is child route of list,
 also can't do anything about ':app/:pattern' )

```
admin - path 'admin'
  L dashboard -> path ''                        - component: DashboardComponent
  L list      -> path ':app/:pattern'           - component: ListComponent
  L detail    -> path ':app/:pattern/detail:id' - component: DetailComponent
```

I'm expected to get breadcrumb like:

```
 Home         > list                       > detail
(path 'admin') (path 'admin/:app/:pattern') (path 'admin/:app/:pattern/detail:id')
```

so approach with 'NavigationEnd' event and 
getting parent Activated route info is not
giving me option to implement this in needed way
since only home is parent route bredcrumb 
will always be only one element Home

My questions are

1. Is there a way to get route info knowing only url path 
   (example in detail component get info about list 'admin/:app/:pattern' path)
2. Or how to implement it another way?

app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/admin', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'admin/login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate [LoginGuard], },
    { path: 'admin/404', component: NotFoundComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], },
    {
        path: 'admin', 
        component: HomeComponent, 
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        data: { breadcrumb: 'Home' },
        children: [
            { path: '', 
              component: DashboardComponent,
              data: { breadcrumb: 'Dashboard' }
            },
            { path: ':app/:pattern', 
              component: ListComponent,
              data: { breadcrumb: 'List' } 
            },
            { path: ':app/:pattern/detail/:id', 
              component: DetailComponent,
              data: { breadcrumb: 'Detail' } 
            },
            { path: ':app/:pattern/action/:id', 
              component: ActionComponent,
              data: { breadcrumb: 'Action' }
            },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: '/admin/404', },
        ]
    },
];
```

Comment: As far as I remember, `NavigationEnd` event has a property called `urlAfterRedirects`. Did you try to use that?

Comment: i cant use urlAfterRedirects (always hassame value as url points ) I need all priewious paths or urls